# Taxed by paycheck or salary?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, payroll-taxes

My company is implementing a review/raise structure where everyone has their review over a 2 month period (July 1st - August 31st).  Everyone then receives their raises on August 31st, backdated from July 1st, for 'fairness' sake.

I am curious, will receiving a large(r) paycheck on August 31st increase the amount of taxes drawn from it?  Or does this entirely depend on how it affects my annual income tax bracket?

I've had trouble finding anything other than tax calculators while searching for this online; any general insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: @MarcusD United States

Comment: OK cant comment. in the UK it would be likely be fine, as tax and NI are calculated across the year based on your tax free limit. cant speak for the US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally in the US, tax withholdings are calculated by extrapolating the check amount against the number of pay roll periods in a year, then considering the standard deduction and number of exemptions you've claimed.

If you receive a retroactive raise and, as a result an abnormally high paycheck, your withholdings will likely be over-estimated on that particular check.  Your company's payroll vendor will likely just assume this check amount is the new normal and calculate accordingly.  This is just a withholding, if it's too much or too little it will be settled when you file your tax return.

Comment: After your first new "normal" check , if you work out how much they're going to over-withhold by, you can file another W-4 with extra exemptions so you break out even for the year.  Just remember to put it back in January!